# Add param to url before other parameters

Tags: jquery

I have an url that looks like this:

```
/Apple-iMac-Core-i5-2-7-GHz-8-GB-1-TB-LED-2?prodid=30811
```

I want to add a parameter before the questionmark so the url looks like this:

```
/Apple-iMac-Core-i5-2-7-GHz-8-GB-1-TB-LED-2?param=prodlist&prodid=30811
```

Today I use a script that switches between two parameters on each click - I want to change this so I have three buttons that each only give one parameters to the url, and each button should replace the parameter with its own value.

Script i use now to switch parameters:

```
$('.click3').on('click', function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
    var baseUrl = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
    var prodid = getParametersByName("prodid");
    var params = getParametersByName("param");

    if (params == "prodlist") 
        param = "grid"; 
    else 
        param = "prodlist";

    var newUrl = baseUrl + "?param=" + param;

    if ((prodid).length > 0) 
        newUrl = newUrl + "&prodid=" + prodid;

    window.location.href = newUrl;

    function getParametersByName(name) { 
        name = name.replace(/[[]/, "\[").replace(/[]]/, "\]"); 
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"), 
            results = regex.exec(location.search); 
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")); 
    } 
});
```

Basically I want something like this, but instead of adding the value After the url - I want it before the parameter already in place.

```
$('.click3').on('click', function() {
    console.log("click3 Clicked");
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.replace(/\?param=.*/,'') + '?param=grid';
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: There is no difference between put the param in the end of the string. In other words, this url: `something.html?param=x&two=y` is exactly the same as this `something.html?two=y&param=x`. Why you need it at start?

Comment: The position of the parameter in the querystring is irrelevant. You can simply append it to the end.

Comment: Im not fully sure - but the system Im working on wont display what I want correctly if the product id isn't at the end: &prodid=30811 - So I need that to work.

Comment: @Rory - it isn't to me, and I need it that way unfortunately.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude it shouldn't mind, but perhaps the server code is parsing the url in an special way that requires a given order of the parameters. It shouldn't be implemented in that way, that's not the expected behavior, but you don't know what is happening in the server side.

Comment: If you get the parameters by a position instead of a key, you are making something wrong. The initial analysis was bad for sure.